# Tetration limit

Tags: limits, tetration

For each $n$, define $f_n:\mathbb R^+\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ by 
$f_n(x) = \underbrace{x^{x^{x^{...^{x^x}}}}}_n$

Is it true that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(\frac{n+1}{n}) = 1$ ?

A few computations using Wolfram Alpha seem to suggest so, but I am unsure of how to prove it.

One way to think about why it might be true intuitively is to compare it to the limit definition of $e$, but even this intuition is handwavy (although it *seems* like it is true based on computations).

Furthermore, I'm unsure if the Binomial expansion actually helps us here.

I'm interested in hearing your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

Tetration to infinite height converges in the range $\left[e^{-e} , e^{\frac1e}\right]$ and nowhere else. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights) for discussion of this, but it's easy enough to see that this restriction must be true if the definition $\displaystyle{e}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}^n$ is to hold.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.  In the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) there is a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aInfinite_power_tower.svg), which gives $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$$

For $e^{-e}<x<e^{1/e}$, this limit exists and is between $e^{-1}$ and $e$.  As $x\rightarrow 1$, the limit approaches 1, just as conjectured by OP.

Comment: I cannot believe that for $x>1$ that limit exists

Comment: Hold on. By $f_3(3)$ here do we mean 3^(3^3) = 3^27 or do we mean (3^3)^3 = 27^3 = 3^9 ?. What I $meant$ to write in the OP is the latter.

Comment: With tetration, the subject of the OP, the parentheses start at the right (i.e. the first of your examples).

Comment: Right, so this is the problem. Time to change the OP

Comment: Ah. So you have a point, vadim123. Haha that's very silly indeed.

Comment: Well, maybe not that silly. Define $f_n(x) = x^{(n-1)x}$, which is what I should have written at the start. Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(\frac{n+1}{n})$ = $ (1+\frac{1}{n})^{(n-\frac{1}{n})}$, which is just $e$. But computations of the first few terms in this "new" $f_n(x)$ seem to get closer and closer to 1, which leaves me wondering where I am now wrong...

Comment: Well, the limit really is $e$

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are all correct.

I believe there is an intuitive way to see $why$ Tetration to infinite height converges for $ x \in [e^{-e},e^{1/e}]$ (although admittedly it is extremely handwavy). I provide and intuitive argument for the above within the range $x<e^{1/e}$. The same argument can probably be applied for $x>e^{-e}$.

Bold Statement: Given $x$ less than but close to $e^{1/e}$, a solution (for $y$) to the equation

$ x^y = y$

exists and is less than $e$.

Take, for example, $1.4 < e^{\frac1e}$.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.4%5Ex+%3D+x

The solution to the equation $1.4^y = y$ we are interested in is 1.88666... .

Trying this for values closer and closer to (but less than) $e^{1/e}$ suggests the "Bold Statement" above, although I haven't really thought about a proof.

We can summarise the Bold Statement by saying that for any given $x<e^{1/e}$ (and with x close to $e^{1/e}$), $f(y) = x^y$ has a "fixed point".

Applying the Contraction Mapping Theorem to $f(y)$ will (hopefully) yield the result which solves the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument $ {n+1 \over n} $ can be rwritten as $ 1+ \frac 1n $ and then one could look at $\lim_{x\to 0} 1+x $ where $x = \frac 1n$. .

Then observe the sequence of Taylor-series of

$f(x)=1+x$,

$f_2(x)=(1+x)^{1+x} =  1 + x + x^2 + 1/2*x^3 + O(x^4)$,

$f_3(x)=(1+x)^{(1+x)^{1+x}} = 1 + x + x^2 + 3/2*x^3 + O(x^4) $,

and so on. You'll find, that the coefficients at the powers of $x$ stabilize one per each iteration. Now assume $n \to \infty$ which means $x \to 0$ and see that the infinite series reduces to the constant $1$, so this makes it much intuitive that indeed the limit is $1$.

I think it is easy to make it formal by considering the power series of $(1+x)^{1+x}=\exp( \log(1+x) \cdot (1+x + O(x^2) ) )$ and induction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)$ be the inverse function of $x\to x^{1/x}$, which is strictly increasing on $[1,e]$, hence $g$ exists and is increasing on $[1,e^{1/e}]$. This definition implies that $x^{g(x)} = g(x)$ because $g(x)^{1/g(x)} = x$.

For any $x\in[1,e^{1/e}]$, We can use induction to show $$
f_n(x) \le g(x)
$$
for all $n$. For the base case, obviously $f_0(x) = x\le g(x)$. If the inequality holds for $n$, then we have that $$
f_{n+1}(x) = x^{f_n(x)} \le x^{g(x)} = g(x)
$$
Therefore, we can conclude by observing $$
1 \le f_n(\frac{1+n}{n}) \le g(\frac{1+n}{n})
$$
$g$ is continuous, so taking the limit on the RHS, we can see that the squeeze theorem implies the limit of $f_n(\frac{1+n}{n})$ is $1$.