# limit about Tetration

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f_0(x)=1$, and $f_{n+1}(x)=x^{f_n(x)}$ for $n\geq 0$.

I have found that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)}{(x-1)^n}=1$ for $n=1,2,3,4$.

It seems like that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)}{(x-1)^n}=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

How to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)}{(x-1)^n}=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/409505/186473